# Scaling up a rect to match scaled bitmap

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bitmap

I have a old Bitmap with size of 320*320 and I crop a rectangle from that bitmap and I get the following rectangle :

```
   val oldRect= RectF(42.884483, 92.28318, 287.36905, 160.71216)
```

I scaled the old bitmap to 3024*4032.

**Now how can I scale the rectangle to match my new bitmap?**

I came up with the following solution but I think it's wrong:

```
      val scaleFactorH = (newBitmap.width / oldBitmap.width).toFloat()
      val scaleFactorV = (newBitmap.height / oldBitmap.height).toFloat()
    
    
        val mX = oldRect.left.toInt() * scaleFactorH
        val mY = oldRect.top.toInt() * scaleFactorV
        val mW = oldRect.right.toInt() * scaleFactorH
        val mH = oldRect.bottom.toInt() * scaleFactorV
    
        val newRect = RecF(mX,mY,mW,mH)
```

Please help me. I have been struggling for days ):

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong? (Apart from rounding everything off with ``toInt()`` for some reason.) Try it with some easy numbers and see if it works!

Comment: @cactustictacs The rectangle is not in the right position in newBitmap. maybe my scaling up code is right but I want to make sure. I will remove `toInt()` and use some numbers and try again. Thanks

Comment: Oh I meant try calculating yourself with some easy numbers, to test if your logic works. Like a 100x100 bitmap with a (25, 25, 75, 75) rectangle, scale it up by 2 or 4, see if the rectangle is still centered on the middle and goes from 25%-75% on both axes. You could also work out what ``mX`` etc *should* be, then put a breakpoint in your code and step through with the debugger to check what's being calculated, work out where it's going wrong (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug if you've never used it, really good to know!)